# Can $\ln x - \sin 2x= 0$ be solved without using computer assisted software?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, maple

The problem is as follows:

$\textrm{Solve and round $x$ to two decimals}$

$$\ln x - \sin 2x= 0$$

There is no indication whether if is allowed to use a calculator or software assistance like Maple. Therefore my first choice was to use any algebraic manipulation if this can be solved that way.

However, the only thing I could come up was to use this:

$$\ln x - \sin 2x= 0$$

$$\ln x - \ln e^{sin 2x}=0$$

$$\ln\left (\frac{x}{e^{\sin 2x}} \right )=0$$

$$\textrm{antiln}\left (\ln\left (\frac{x}{e^{\sin 2x}} \right ) \right)= \textrm{antiln} (0)$$

$$\frac{x}{e^{\sin 2x}}= 1$$

$$x-e^{\sin 2x}=0$$

But it got stuck here, moreover, If I try to use the inverse function of the sine equation does not help much.

I'm also confused about this step with logarithm manipulation:

If I use the $\textrm{antiln}$ just straight at the beginning of the equation;

$$\ln x - \sin 2x= 0$$

$$\textrm{antiln}\left( \ln x- \sin 2x \right ) = \textrm{antiln} (0)$$

Would become into:

$$x - e^{\sin 2x}= e^{0}=1$$

But this latter equation does not seem the same of what I obtained before. Did I misunderstood something?. I need assistance with these doubts.

Edit:

Now moving onto Maple (which is the part which has not yet been answered):

I tried using this command:

```
solve(ln(x)-sin(2*x)=0,x)
```

and I got:

$$1/2*\textrm{RootOf}\left(_Z-2\exp(sin(_Z))\right )$$

I don't know what does it mean?, and why it does not produce a numeric result?. Can somebody help me with this matter?.

I'd like also some help how to make Maple to plot a graph of the function showing the answer. How do I achieve this?.

Comment: No, applying the antilogarithm (aka $e^x$) first would lead to $e^{\ln x - \sin 2x} = {x \over e^{\sin 2x}}$ which is the same expression. Subtracting exponents is dividing the bases.

Comment: Also I don't think you can solve this analytically. WA gives a numerical approximation.

Comment: @AndrewLi Thanks for reminding me about the mistake what I did in the latter part of the antilogarithm. Sorry. I also tried WA as you mentioned and I confirmed that it produces a number but I'm looking if somebody knows if it can be solved analytically and of course what does it mean the answer Maple produces.

Comment: If you aren't allowed a computer, are you allowed a calculator or at least tables?

Comment: @RossMillikan As it is mentioned, there is no clear caveat regarding not using a calculator. So I assume yes I can use any assistance available my question was if it can be solved without using such tools and what was the meaning of the answer that I obtained with Maple, to which the latter part has not yet been answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly doubt you will be able to solve this equation analytically for $x$; it is a [transcendental equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) where the variable appears in both arguments of transcendental functions. This will require some numerical methods to solve such as iterative root-finding methods.

You can employ Newton's which is given by

$$ x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}, $$

where $$ f(x) = \ln(x) -\sin (2x), \quad f'(x) = \frac{1}{x_n} - 2\cos(2x_n).  $$

Using an initial value $x_0 = 1/2$, WA gives the following $x = 1.399942...$ reaching machine precision after $7$ iterations. The associated diagram is given by

[image]

**In response to OP's comments:**

Determining a *suitable* initial guess $x_0$ can present some issues. I would advise you consult the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) for more details. One way in determining a good initial guess is to plot the functions. This gives a rough value for $x_0$ value by inspection.

The [RoofOf output](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=RootOf) is what Maple produces for solve-for equations. It is a placeholder for all the roots of some variable. You can then apply various functions to this such as evalf etc. to get some numerical result.

The [video lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z140r84uIQ0&t=931s) by MapleSoft shows how to utilise the Student[Calculus1] package in Maple. It discusses

- Root finding methods.
- Display the corresponding graph with tangent lines similar to the WA output.

Comment: Can you kindly tell me what is the commend of WA to specific what numerical method to approximate with? Appreciation in advance

Comment: @Holo Sure. The commands are as follows; solve $f(x) = 0$ using Newton's method. You can also select Secant or bisection method.

Comment: @Rumplestillskin Why should I start from $\frac{1}{2}$ for Newton's method? How could I get to that conclusion beforehand?. Is it a value assumed randomly?. There is a second part of the problem which has not yet been answered of what is the meaning of the answer I got from Maple and how can I obtain the graph you obtained using Maple?

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell  I have updated my answer for clarity.

Comment: @Rumplestillskin You hit the nail in the head about how to select the initial guess when using the Newton method. I've read the wiki article and it helped. But one way or another it looks that transcendental equations cannot be solved analytically and in the end i'll need to resort to some kind of software aid.

Comment: @Rumplestillskin  Regarding the RootOf output i've checked the Maple entry and it is suffice to say that I can take it from there, the same goes for the use of Student[Calculus1] package you mentioned, thanks about that. However I'm still baffled how other answers have reached to the value of $\frac{\pi}{2}$. I know is not "the" answer but around it. Could it be because $\sin(2\times\frac{\pi}{2})=0$? If so Why not choosing $1$ since that value would make $\ln (1)=0$? Either way I used both on Newton Raphson and I can reach to $1.3994$ as you pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is clearly around $\frac \pi 2$.

So, for an *approximation* of the root, use the Taylor expansion built around this point and get
$$\log (x)-\sin (2 x)=\log \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)+\left(2+\frac{2}{\pi }\right) \left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\frac{2 \left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^2}{\pi
   ^2}+O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^3\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, solve the quadratic in $\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ . This would give
$$x=\frac{1}{2} \left(2 \pi +\pi ^2-\sqrt{\pi ^2+2 \pi ^3+\pi ^4+2 \pi ^2 \log
   \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)}\right)\approx 1.40172 $$ while the exact solution is $\approx 1.39943$ and this is not too bad.

Sooner or later, you will learn that, better than Taylor series, functions can be locally approximated using Padé approximants. The simplest $[1,1]$  would write
$$f(x)=\frac{f(a)+\frac{ \left(2 f'(a)^2-f(a) f''(a)\right)}{2 f'(a)}(x-a)}{1-\frac{
   f''(a)}{2 f'(a)}(x-a)}$$ Then, just solving, for your case, this would give
$$x=\frac \pi 2 \left(1+\frac{(1+\pi ) \log \left(\frac{4}{\pi ^2}\right)}{2 (1+\pi )^2+\log
   \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)} \right)\approx 1.40175$$

If you use Newton methods, the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.570796327 \\
 1 & 1.399522975 \\
 2 & 1.399428868 \\
 3 & 1.399428866
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Can you tell me how did you obtained $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to be a solution to the equation?. It's been a time since I learned Taylor series, can you explain how to obtain the Taylor expansion for the sine function. I'm stuck at that part in your answer. Can you show it more explicitly? I'm not familiar with [Padé approximants] (https://bit.ly/2tKb8qC) the article in Wikipedia is not very helpful. Perhaps can you explain it a bit how you used it in this problem?. I mean I understand the notations of derivatives but where does [1,1] comes from?.

Comment: I think stating "the solution is clearly around $\pi/2$" isn't very helpful to the OP. If it was so clear I am sure (s)he wouldn't have any issues with the question at hand.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the problem is to solve $\, \ln x - \sin 2x= 0 \,$ using hand calculation to two decimal place accuracy. A brief sketch shows that $x < \pi/2$ but not by much. More precisely, let $\, x = (1 - t) \pi/2 \,$ where $\, t \,$ is is the fraction by which $\, x \,$ is less than $\, \pi/2, \,$ and we guess that $\, t  \,$ is **much** less than $\,1.\,$

Using this we get the first term becomes
 $\, \ln x = \ln( (1 - t) \pi/2) = \ln (1-t) +\ln (\pi / 2) .\,$
The second term becomes
 $\, \sin 2x = \sin((1 - t) \pi)  = \sin(\pi - \pi t) =  \sin(\pi t). \,$
Using these the equation becomes
 $\, \ln (1-t) +\ln (\pi / 2) - \sin(\pi t) = 0. \,$
Since $\, t \,$ is **small**, simple [**linear approximation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_approximation) gives us
 $\, \ln(1 - t) \approx -t \,$ and $\, \sin(\pi t) \approx \pi t. \,$
Using these approximations we get
 $\, - t + \ln(\pi/2) - \pi t = 0. \,$ By algebraic simplification we get
 $\, \ln (\pi /2) \approx (\pi + 1) t. \,$ Solving for $\, t \,$ gives
 $\, t \approx (\ln (\pi /2))/(\pi + 1). \,$ Calculation now gives
 $\, t \approx 0.11 \,$ and $\, x \approx 1.40. \,$

Comment: Where does $\frac{\pi}{2}$ value comes from?. Why $x=(1-t)\frac{\pi}{2}$?. The rest from there I'm lost. Why $\sin(\pi t)- \ln (1-t)$?. Can you explain this part?. Maybe you can develop a little bit more your answer?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell I have expanded my answer. I hope it is more understandable.

Comment: Thanks for expanding a bit your answer but I'm stuck at the approximation of $\ln(1-t)\approx -t$ and $\sin(\pi t)\approx \pi t$. How do I prove that? Why do we establish these are the approximations?. I can understand better if you add an explanation to this part in your answer. If you explain that I can take it from the rest.